# Matplotlib legend colors differ from plot colors - bug or error?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, legend, errorbar, jupyter-lab

I plot data with error bars and want to label them in the legend. However, the colors in the legend don't match the colors in the plot.

toy example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(50),label='data')
plt.errorbar(np.arange(50),np.arange(50),yerr=np.arange(50),label='errors')
plt.legend()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Is this behavior a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

I am using python 2.7 and jupyter lab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line for the `plot` as well as one for the `errorbar`. One hides the other.

You may set the `linestyle` of the errorbar to `"None"`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(50),label='data')
plt.errorbar(np.arange(50),np.arange(50),yerr=np.arange(50),ls="None",
             label='errors')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

You may also set the `zorder` of the plot to a higher number to let it appear in front.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider that `plt.errorbar()` has two color parameters:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(50),color='blue',label='data')
plt.errorbar(np.arange(0,50,2),np.arange(0,50,2),yerr=np.arange(0,50,2),color='blue',ecolor='red',label='errors')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: technically not the answer to my question, but extremely helpful! I wish I could accept two answers.